# Are there such things as online development projects?

Tags: software-engineering, project-management

I would like to practice a bit as a programmer in the gaming field but know of no one making games in my proximity. I was wondering if there is an online community or something where people look for other developers for their projects? I mean as in simple independent stuff, not paid of course, it would be just to get practice and maybe be able to complete something. Any pointer appreciated.

Comment: The answer is yes, such things exist, but recommending one is outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 1):

A well-known community to bring programmers together is [GitHub](https://github.com/explore).

It is primarily a website to host [Git](http://git-scm.com/) repositories for open source projects, but makes it easy to collaborate by allowing to create forks of the projects of other people and then offering them to pull the improvements you made.

It is not only a community specifically for *game* programmers, but I know several open source game projects which collaborate via GitHub.

Comment: +1, there are **a lot** games on github in many different programming-languages. You just need to know how google works and you'll find projects you can contribute to.